# MAC address ends with FF:FF:FF

Tags: security, network-adapter, mac-address

My PCs MAC address ends with `FF:FF:FF`. I am little confused about this address. As per my knowledge MAC address is of 12 Hex digits (first 6 correspond to Company and second half to a unique NIC). And as NIC numbers may be between `00:00:00` and `FF:FF:FF` (both exclusive).

`00:00:00` and `FF:FF:FF` are not assigned.

Is this a manufacturing mistake?

Comment: Are you sure that this address isn't changed in your network card preferences?

Comment: How it can be changed? Isn't that a fix Address.

Comment: Not necessarily, it is a fix address and you can't rewrite that directly in interface, but you may override it by system settings. If you are using windows that it is in "Preferences -> Configuration" of that network device. In Linux you can change it by command `ifconfig eth0 hw ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff`.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that all 0's or all F's have special group meanings, but that includes the vendor ID, so a FF-FF-FF in the OUI is fine as long as the vendorID portion is not FF-FF-FF as well.